# Is there any equivalent in Snowflake for OBJECT_ID() in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The OBJECT_ID function Returns the database object identification number of a schema-scoped object in SQL SERVER.
Could anyone suggest an equivalent function in Snowflake that can be used inside a stored procedure?
I need to migrate the below code to Snowflake:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure
(@Var1 INT )
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Var1 = 1
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('db1.Table1') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE Table1;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: Snowflake would likely need you to query the `information_schame.tables` to check for the existence of a table.

Comment: Better question is why you need this stored procedure at all? You can obviously accomplish the same thing searching metadata by name and schema but the idea of dropping a permanent table within a procedure is questionable.

Comment: @SMor brings up a good point.  In addition to that, Snowflake has the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` option, so you could just run that without having to check on its existence.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('db1.Table1') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE Table1;
```

is the old way to check if table exists before trying to drop it.

Currently both [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/drop-table.html) supports `IF EXISTS` clause:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <table_name>;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48821159f1ba6ed24ca763e2cefeade3)**

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can think of will be to use a function like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OBJECT_ID(NAME VARCHAR) RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS 
$$
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA || '.' ||  OBJECT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.OBJECT_PRIVILEGES WHERE 
       (OBJECT_SCHEMA || '.' || OBJECT_NAME) = NAME
$$;
```

The snowflake [object_privileges view](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/object_privileges.html) is the closest information_schema view listing all db elements.

However as noted on previous answers, the `IF EXISTS` on create and drop statements, makes the usage of this function unnecessary

Comment: As a note. It seems that OBJECT_PRIVILEGES has a interesting behavior with temporary tables. If in one session you create the table, the object_privileges tables show the temporary table. As a workaround for temporary tables they can be checked inside the information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE='LOCAL TEMPORARY'